# React Jest Test coverage showing untested line (default props)

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I am running a test on the simple button component. All works fine, however, in the test coverage I am getting an untested line (21: `onClick: () => { return true }`). This line points to the default props function. How can I make sure that I have covered the unit test for this line?

My component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export const Button = (props) => {
  return (
    <Link 
      to={props.link} 
      className={props.classes}
      onClick={props.onClick}
    >
      {props.title}
    </Link>
  );
};

Button.defaultProps = {
  link: '/',
  title: 'Home',
  classes: 'btn btn--primary',
  onClick: () => { return true }
}

Button.propTypes = {
  link: PropTypes.string,
  title: PropTypes.string,
  classes: PropTypes.string,
  onClick: PropTypes.func
};

export default Button;
```

My test:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { Button } from '../../../components/partials/Button';

test('should render button', () => {

  const wrapper = shallow(<Button link='/test' title='Home' classes='btn btn--primary' onClick={ () => { return true }} />);
  expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
  const props = wrapper.props();
  expect(props.to).toBe('/test');
  expect(props.className).toBe('btn btn--primary');
  expect(props.onClick).toBe(props.onClick);
  expect(props.children).toBe('Home');
});


test('should have default onClick', () => {
  expect(Button.defaultProps.onClick).toBeDefined();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the `onClick` function in order for it to count for coverage. So, make a test that simulates a click event on the button, which will trigger its `onClick` function:

```
it('does something when clicked', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Button link='/test' title='Home' classes='btn btn--primary' onClick={ () => { return true }} />);

    wrapper.simulate('click');
    expect(...);
});
```

Comment: thank you so much for the answer. It seems I have a problem with the expect(...). I have searched StackOverflow and tried at least 8 suggested solutions, however, none of those would work. I found also that instead of .simulate('click') I should be testing for props instead - quote I found: "Even though the name would imply this simulates an actual event, .simulate() will, in fact, target the component's prop based on the event you give it. For example, .simulate('click') will actually get the onClick prop and call it."